# Search a folder in a document library with PnP

Tags: document-library, spfx, search-results, pnp, search-query

how can I search on a document library for the folders containg a specific name? where is the doc for that?

I want to seach my document library "MyDocs" for folders containing, in the title, a specific code

What I tried

```
  const rootPath = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/";
  const rootFolder = "MyDocs";

  const searchQuerySettings = {
    TrimDuplicates: false,
    RowLimit: 1,
    // ?? SelectProperties: ["Title"]
  }

  const query = SearchQueryBuilder(
    `iscontainer:true path:${rootPath}${rootFolder} title:*${item.code}*`,
    searchQuerySettings);
```

and I get not really OK as result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for people having same issue, fixed the

```
`iscontainer:true path:${rootPath}${rootFolder} title:*${item.code}*`,
```

to

```
`contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary iscontainer:true path:${rootPath}${rootFolder} title:"${item.code}"`,
```

so, the main modification is `*` => `"` in title